# Windows 10 Ubuntu Bash Shell: How Do I Mount Other Windows Drives?

Tags: windows-10, bash, mount

I'm using Windows 10's Ubuntu Bash shell. It maps the C drive fine as /mnt/c.

I have other local physical hard drives, mounted in Windows as E: and F:

How do I tell Bash to mount these drives too (ideally automatically at /mnt/e and /mnt/f, but manual mounting is fine)? "sudo fdisk -l" doesn't seem to work (cannot open /proc/partitions), so I'm not sure how to find their names, otherwise I'd just use a regular mount command.

Comment: Are you sure they aren't there (/mnt/e etc)? That's where they should be by default. https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2016/03/30/run-bash-on-ubuntu-on-windows/

Comment: `Mounting is currently not supported and something that we are aware of. We will be looking at the User Voice page to prioritize what features to light up next. So, please do provide your feedback there as well.` - From Microsoft themselves. You'll have to wait till it's fixed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Accessing removable media in Bash on Windows](https://superuser.com/questions/1109993/accessing-removable-media-in-bash-on-windows)

Answer (score 151):

Good news, it is now possible to mount USB media (including formatted as FAT) and network shares with drvfs on Windows 10:

Mount removable media: (e.g. D:)

```
$ sudo mkdir /mnt/d
$ sudo mount -t drvfs D: /mnt/d
```

To safely unmount

```
$ sudo umount /mnt/d
```

You can also mount network shares without smbfs:

```
$ sudo mount -t drvfs '\\server\share' /mnt/share
```

You need at least Build 16176 so you might have to opt-in to the Windows Insider programm and then update Windows. Source: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/wsl/2017/04/18/file-system-improvements-to-the-windows-subsystem-for-linux/

Comment: Hi David, thanks for your suggestion. Feel free to indicate duplication. This answer is well tailored to the question. Feel free to edit it if you can improve it or comment with suggestions if you don't have the reputation to do that.

Comment: The OPS asked "how do I mount...", so IMHO this is the answer I appreciated the most (and as a bonus, even offers the answer to mount network shares)

Comment: Can this be made permanent? I have tried to follow guidance on modifying /etc/fstab for regular linux, but they don't seem to apply to WSL.

Comment: @AdamCrossland: That has been added recently. Check if you have at least Windows version 10.0.17093. Open a shell with "cmd" and run "ver" to check. If you have an older version you need to upgrade. You probably have to opt-in to Windows Insider updates first. Source: https://github.com/Microsoft/WSL/issues/2636#issuecomment-364172586

Comment: Found this in 2020. Is it reasonable to have a recurring script to check if a windows drive has been added, then run the linux command to mount the drive?

this might be the solution. hoping someone with more experience in powershell & task scheduling can recognise if this is viable or best solution in 2020.
https://superuser.com/questions/219401/starting-scheduled-task-by-detecting-connection-of-usb-device

Answer (score 16):

> To facilitate interoperability with Windows, WSL uses the DrvFs file system. WSL automatically mounts all fixed drives with supported file systems under /mnt, such as /mnt/c, /mnt/d, etc. Currently, only NTFS and ReFS volumes are supported.

From: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/wsl/2016/06/15/wsl-file-system-support/

If `e:` and `f:` have other filesystems like `FAT`, `exFAT`, they will not be automatically mounted.

Comment: Makes sense. Those drives are ext4 volumes and mounted using ext2fsd from http://www.ext2fsd.com/ and I never would have imagined they wouldn't be recognized by a Linux kernel. That explains why.

Comment: @JasonChampion: with Windows 10's Ubuntu Bash shell there is *no Linux kernel*. That's why it wouldn't work before.

Comment: @mementum but in my case the filesystem is ɴᴛꜰꜱ and it doesn’t mount anyway.

Answer (score 4):

Those other drives *should* be there as well, in /mnt/e etc. You can check with `ls /mnt`. If they aren't, I'd try one of several things-

-Reboot your computer, make sure that the drives are plugged in, and then launch bash

-Reinstall Ubuntu by running `lxrun/uninstall/full/y` and then `lxrun/install/y` in cmd

-If nothing works, you can try making a symlink from the mount point of the usb drive to some folder on your C drive. I believe [this](http://lifehacker.com/5496652/how-to-use-symlinks-in-windows) article explains how to make them in Windows.

If none of this works, I would recommend reporting this as a bug to Microsoft. WSL is still under heavy development, and not nearly all of the features are working properly.

Answer (score 2):

Consider a slight alternative on the [currently top voted answer](https://superuser.com/a/1209698/1210833):

```bash
sudo mkdir /mnt/<usb_drive_letter>
sudo mount -t drvfs <usb_drive_letter>: /mnt/<usb_drive_Letter> -o uid=$(id -u $USER),gid=$(id -g $USER),metadata
```

For a USB drive which is assigned in Windows to `H:`, for example:

```bash
sudo mkdir /mnt/h
sudo mount -t drvfs h: /mnt/h -o uid=$(id -u $USER),gid=$(id -g $USER),metadata
```

In general, the other method will work, but note that drives that are manually mounted this way do not follow the normal WSL automount settings.

Most *fixed* Windows drives will be mounted:

- In `/mnt/<drive_letter` for each drive.
- With the default WSL user and its primary group as the owner of the mount.
- A default umask/fmask/dmask of 000
- The `metadata` disabled for performance, which means only a "simplified permission" model will be used to map Windows/NTFS and Linux permissions.

However, USB drives that are manually mounted do not follow the [`[automount]`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/wsl-config#automount-options) settings.

At the very least, you'll probably want your WSL user to be the owner, which is done with the `-o uid=$(id -u $USER),gid=$(id -g $USER)` (usually, this is the same as `-o uid=1000,gid=1000` in a default Ubuntu/WSL installation).

Adding in the `metadata` option can be useful if you want to preserve permissions via `rsync` or `cp -a`.

Comment: Nice post nerd.  +1.  I use WSL every day and didn't know this.  Makes sense.. follows unix mount.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas Lol - And thanks!  Same here -- I just happened to notice it when answering an Ask Ubuntu question earlier today.  I thought for sure that manually mounted drvfs drives would use the `[automount]` settings, although in retrospect that seems counterintuitive.

Answer (score 0):

Very late to this party but here's the official issue: https://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/266908-command-prompt-console-bash-on-ubuntu-on-windo/suggestions/13355724-unable-to-access-usb-devices-from-bash

In short, it's on their radar but it's not implemented yet. :(

Comment: The question is about local drives.

Answer (score -4):

Try this only If you are using WSL Linux (downloaded from Microsoft Store)

1.`cd /mnt`
2.`cd D/`

First part is something like start mounting and then you can simply add any drives.

Comment: All this does is change the current directory, it does not actually mount anything