# Accessing EXT2 drive from "Bash on Ubuntu on Windows"

Tags: ubuntu, windows-10, bash, ext2

I am wondering if it is possible to access a EXT2 formatted partition from Bash in Windows 10. I already have "Ext2 IFS For Windows", so I am able to read/write to this partition from Windows explorer already. But this partition is not showing up in /mnt.

The reason why I need to do this is because my machine has dual boot between Ubuntu and Windows. And before Windows 10 came out, I was doing a lot of development work in Ubuntu, saving in the EXT2 partition so that if I need to access it from Windows side, I could do so using Ext2 IFS. Now, with Bash for Windows, I am considering doing my development work all in Windows; however, I need to be able to access my files that are currently in the Ext2 partition first.

Comment: [Windows 10 Ubuntu Bash Shell: How Do I Mount Other Windows Drives?](https://superuser.com/q/1114341/241386), [Access Ubuntu partition files using Windows bash](https://askubuntu.com/q/906664/253474), https://github.com/Microsoft/BashOnWindows/issues/579