# Does Windows 10 now support EXT4?

Tags: windows, filesystems, ext4

I recently updated my home PC from Windows 7 Pro to Windows 10 Pro via the inline update tool (update existing installation.) This went smoothly with no notable issues.

Upon completing the update I noticed that my dual boot Ext4 Ubuntu install was now accessible from within Windows. This was not previously possible (I had used “ext2 reader” to access some files, but it's not a full FS driver.)

It also works with my Raspberry Pi filesystems on external drivea and SD cards. Explorer states that the filesystem is "Ext4".

However, I can't for the life of me find any documentation for this change or feature. It seems to be a frequently requested one, but all suggestions say to use this or that method and none suggest native support.

Am I completely losing the plot here? Is this a new feature or not? If not, what on earth is going on?

Comment: What version of Windows 10? And do you have wsl installed?

Comment: This is probably a good place to start reading: https://superuser.com/questions/1245210/access-ubuntu-partition-from-windows-sub-system

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Access Ubuntu partition from Windows sub-system](https://superuser.com/questions/1245210/access-ubuntu-partition-from-windows-sub-system)