# Why can I not mount my NTFS local partition on Bash for Windows

Tags: windows-10, bash, mount, nfs, ubuntu-16.04

I have two local disks on my Windows 10 OS, C:/ and W:/ (w:/ is an NTFS partition of my C: drive). I start up Bash on Ubuntu on Windows, and under `/mnt/` I only see one directory, `/mnt/c`. Following [this](https://superuser.com/questions/1114341/windows-10-ubuntu-bash-shell-how-do-i-mount-other-windows-drives) question on mounting an ntfs USB drive, when I try to mount the drive using `sudo mount -t drvfs W: w`, the following error occurs:

```
mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on W:,
       missing codepage or helper program, or other error

       In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
       dmesg | tail or so.
```

How do I go about resolving this error? Most questions I see relating to this say that the partition should have automatically come up in `/mnt`, so why would this situation be different?

Comment: Hi, have you tried looking into `/media/`?

Comment: @dmb yes, it's empty unfortunately