# Mount CD drive in Windows 10 bash

Tags: windows-10, bash, mount

It's not something to explain in detail. It's just simply, how do I mount my CD drive in Windows 10's bash?

I have no idea whether it's even possible or not. HDDs and folders can easily be mounted and linked, but the cdrom has me completely mind boggled.

---

> Your question has been identified as a possible duplicate of [another question](https://superuser.com/questions/1109993). If the answers there do not address your problem, please edit to explain in detail the parts of your question that are unique.

Well that's debatable. That question clarifies the use of external drives and removable disks isn't supported, but my question is about the CD drive. CD's are considered removable in the same sense of a USB drive in some situations, but the CD drive is a static device. It should be mountable.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Accessing removable media in Bash on Windows](http://superuser.com/questions/1109993/accessing-removable-media-in-bash-on-windows)

Comment: I don't think so. I edited my question to explain why.

Comment: For fixed drives, see [this question](http://superuser.com/questions/1114341/windows-10-ubuntu-bash-shell-how-do-i-mount-other-windows-drives). Short version, only NTFS and ReFS volumes are supported. CDs are usually ISO9660, and DVDs are usually UDF.